# I have found the Rth=10 ohms, However i can't find the thevenin's voltage(between a &b)

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current-source, thevenin, voltage-source

*I converted the wye network into a delta and found the equivalent resistances in parallel and series and got it to be 10 ohms. However i am stuck at trying to find Vth. I tried applying mesh analysis and found the two mesh currents(source conversion to the center branch was done to obtain a single branch of 50V in series with 10 ohms)

***Please do guide me o*n how to solve this problem.***

[[image: The circuit is given below]]

Comment: First, show us how you found Rth = 10Ohms. And then, show us your effort on finding Vth and where you got stuck at.

Comment: I converted the wye network into a delta and found the equivaient resistances in parallel and series and got it to be 10 ohms. However i am stuck at trying to find Vth. I tried applying mesh analysis and found the two mesh currents(source conversion to the center branch was done).

Comment: Alright, but show these in the question body. You can use the **Edit** button and edit your question by adding the details. People here may not read your explanation under the **Comments** section.

Comment: You can use superposition.

Comment: I got the answer to be 10 V. Please do confirm if someone's tried it. Thanks

Comment: 10V is the correct value for Vth.

Comment: Yes, 10V is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fITtZN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_6+\text{I}_8\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_6+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_9\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_\text{k}+\text{I}_9\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_\text{k}+\text{I}_8
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_7}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

And we also know that \$\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4=\text{V}_\text{p}\$.

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_7}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_6}+\text{I}_8\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_6}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_7}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}+\text{I}_9\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}=\text{I}_\text{k}+\text{I}_9\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}=\text{I}_\text{k}+\text{I}_8
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can solve for using your values:

- $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\lim_{\text{R}_7\to\infty}\left(\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3\right)=10\space\text{V}\tag4$$
- $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\lim_{\text{R}_7\to0}\text{I}_7=1\space\text{A}\tag5$$
- $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{th}}{\text{I}_\text{th}}=10\space\Omega\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-codes:

```
In[1]:=Vi = 30;
Vp = 20;
Ik = 5;
R1 = 10;
R2 = 10;
R3 = 10;
R4 = 20;
R5 = 10;
R6 = 20;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I7, I2 == I4 + I6 + I8, I5 == I4 + I6 + I7, 
   I1 == I5 + I9, I3 == Ik + I9, I3 == Ik + I8, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, 
   I2 == (V1 - V2)/R2, I3 == V2/R3, I4 == (V2 - V3)/R4, I5 == V3/R5, 
   I6 == (V2 - V4)/R6, I7 == (V1 - V3)/R7, V3 - V4 == Vp}, {I1, I2, 
   I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, I8, I9, V1, V2, V3, V4}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> 5/(10 + R7), I2 -> -(5/(10 + R7)), I3 -> 3, 
  I4 -> (5 + R7)/(20 + 2 R7), I5 -> 2 + 5/(10 + R7), 
  I6 -> (25 + 3 R7)/(20 + 2 R7), I7 -> 10/(10 + R7), I8 -> -2, 
  I9 -> -2, V1 -> 30 - 50/(10 + R7), V2 -> 30, 
  V3 -> 20 + 50/(10 + R7), V4 -> 50/(10 + R7)}}

In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(30 - 50/(10 + R7)) - (20 + 50/(10 + R7)), R7 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=10

In[3]:=FullSimplify[Limit[10/(10 + R7), R7 -> 0]]

Out[3]=1

In[4]:=FullSimplify[%2/%3]

Out[4]=10
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify and add a label.

[image]

The sum of the currents into c:

(30-Vc)/20 + (50-Vc)/10 + (-10-Vc)/20 = 0

Vc = 30,
Va = 30,
Vb = 20,
Va-Vb = Vth = 10